# DB2 SQL Select Statement & Group By

Tags: sql, db2

I am having trouble getting my query to group correctly. I need to include the `TELLERACTIVITY.ENTRY_DATE` date column so I can filter by the date later on. However, I do not want it to group by the `TELLERACTIVITY.ENTRY_DATE` date because it gives me more results than I want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACTIVITYINFO.MEMBER_NBR AS "Member Number"
   ,ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NBR AS "Account Number"
   ,TELLERACTIVITY.FOCUS_TELLER_ID AS "Teller ID"
   ,TELLERACTIVITY.ENTRY_DATE AS "Date"
   ,SUM(( CASE WHEN OPERATOR.BRANCH_NBR = 1 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END )) AS "Branch 1"
   ,SUM(( CASE WHEN OPERATOR.BRANCH_NBR = 2 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END )) AS "Branch 2"
   ,SUM(( CASE WHEN OPERATOR.BRANCH_NBR = 3 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END )) AS "Branch 3"
   ,SUM(( CASE WHEN OPERATOR.BRANCH_NBR = 4 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END )) AS "Branch 4"
FROM TELLERACTIVITY
JOIN OPERATOR
    ON TELLERACTIVITY.FOCUS_TELLER_ID = OPERATOR.OPR_NBR
JOIN ACTIVITY
    ON TELLERACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_ID = ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_ID
       AND TELLERACTIVITY.FOCUS_TELLER_ID = ACTIVITY.FOCUS_TELLER_ID
       AND TELLERACTIVITY.ENTRY_DATE = ACTIVITY.ENTRY_DATE
JOIN ACTIVITYINFO
    ON ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_ID = ACTIVITYINFO.ACTIVITY_ID
JOIN ACCOUNT
    ON ACTIVITYINFO.MEMBER_NBR = ACCOUNT.MEMBER_NBR
       AND ACTIVITYINFO.ACCOUNT_NBR = ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NBR
WHERE TELLERACTIVITY.FOCUS_TELLER_ID < 6000
GROUP BY ACTIVITYINFO.MEMBER_NBR
   ,ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NBR
   ,OPERATOR.BRANCH_NBR
   ,TELLERACTIVITY.FOCUS_TELLER_ID
   ,TELLERACTIVITY.ENTRY_DATE
ORDER BY ACTIVITYINFO.MEMBER_NBR
```

Comment: What do you mean you need to filter it by `TELLERACTIVITY.ENTRY_DATE` (I assume you refer to this column) later on?

Comment: Why can't you add the date filtering to your where clause?

Comment: I will add it to my where clause as soon as I get it to not group by date. :)

Comment: You don't need to group by date in order to have date in your where clause.

Comment: I know lol I am just saying I am trying to fix this problem of the date being grouped first before I move on to the next step. If I have the date grouped which it is now it gives more results than I want.

Comment: grr tried to show sample output but it wont go in correct format

Comment: Don't use `DISTINCT` - it isn't a panacea to replace understanding your data correctly.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the concept of `GROUP BY`. Either you want to include the `ENTRY_DATE` in the clustering columns for each group because you want the sum _per date_, or each group can consolidate rows with different dates. Note that this will affect the `SUM()`s you are retrieving.

Comment: @Turophile - Agree that the OP seems to be confused about the use of `GROUP BY`, and that `DISTINCT` isn't the way to go here.  However, the **only** way to guarantee order in an SQL statement is to use `ORDER BY` - even if the db engine _does_ sort during grouping (which is plausible), there's no guarantee that that order will be retained, or is even the one you anticipate - for instance, what if it reads the rows for grouping in _reverse_ order?  If you want rows in a specific order, use `ORDER BY`, otherwise consider it undefined.

Comment: Only use `DISTINCT` when not doing aggregating (ie, no `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, etc) and your base data has duplicate values, otherwise use `GROUP BY`.  In almost every case, the start of your `SELECT` list should match your `GROUP BY` clause - otherwise, you have essentially a "mystery" division (that is, you should remove `OPERATOR.BRANCH_NBR` from your `GROUP BY`, because it's not really helping you).

Comment: @ Clockwork-Muse you are right about `ORDER BY` still being required. For "casual queries" the `GROUP BY` usually gives what you need, but isn't sufficient to guarantee the order. I will delete that comment.